# Changing UIStatusBarStyle to LightContent (white) not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I am having a lot of trouble trying to change the status bar color to white in Swift. I have checked all the questions related to this here and non of the solutions seem to work properly. Right now I'm using the key in info.plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to `NO`. In my AppDelegate.Swift I have:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)
    return true
}
```

The bar is white now but I have an error in the console:

> Error: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.*

Has anyone managed to figure out how to do this cleanly? Any tips would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a light content style across your entire app, you don't need code. You've already changed "View controller-based status bar appearance" to `NO`, so now all you need to do is select your project in the project navigator pane, then choose the General tab and look for the Status Bar Style dropdown – it's in the Deployment Info section, just underneath Device Orientation.

As you can see in the screenshot below, just change that to be Light and you're done.

[image: Changing status bar style to light]

Comment: This works, I have removed the code from the AppDelegate.swift however I'm still getting those errors in the console.

Comment: I'm glad it works; please mark the answer as correct so others can find it easily! If the error is still there, a) it's possible there's something else in your code that's causing it (not your status bar), or b) it's an Apple problem. Apple does have a tendency to leave strange error messages in, which can be quite confusing.

Comment: I don't have any other code yet. If I don't have the key in the plist then the bar stays black. If the key is in the plist it works but I'm getting that error message...seems strange

Answer (score 1):

This question has a deprecated answer.

'setStatusBarStyle(_:animated:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

Use like this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```